# Cannot display name with special character in highchart

Tags: asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I have an MVC app that uses HighCharts to display a graph. The problem I have is with displaying this name (Münning) in the title of the graph. Notice the symbol over the "ü".

The below highchart markup shows the last thing I have tried. However, when the chart is displayed, the title shows this for the company name: "Münning".

How can I get the company name to display with the special character?

```
title:
{
text: '@string.Format("{0} - {1:MM/dd/yyyy}", ViewBag.CompanyName, ViewBag.Date)'
},
```

Comment: have you tried `@Html.Raw(Model.text)`? But it looks like you're trying to use server side code with client side variables?

Comment: will post as answer for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [@Html.Raw(Model.text)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx) in order to pass special characters.

It *Returns markup that is not HTML encoded.* Meaning that you don't get the problem with encoding/decoding special characters at all.

As a side note, I would try to avoid the use of `@ViewBag` / `ViewData` as much as possible (as they were only included as a convenience and not to be overused/abused).